# How to select following-sibling with XPath

Tags: xpath

[image]

My xpath: `//*[@id="NovaposhtaRegistrationRequestForm_MiddleName"]`
but I don't need input field, I need next line (keyboard icon).
How to down on one line? Or how to get it?

Comment: Sorry! And how i can write xpath for it ?

Comment: https://clip2net.com/clip/m391408/891b4-clip-111kb.png?nocache=1

Comment: This seem to be another issue. Consider to open new ticket for this issue and share solutions you've already tried

Answer (score 0):

If you need following sibling node, you can try [appropriate axis](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp)

```
//*[@id="NovaposhtaRegistrationRequestForm_MiddleName"]/following-sibling::span
```